Degeneracies of the Dirac Equation
When one computes the solutions of the Dirac equation by employing the plane-wave ansatz, one obtains 4 solutions of the Dirac equation: with two solutions being positive energy solutions with same energy and the other two being negative energy solutions, again, with the same energy.
As this describes a degeneracy in the system, there must be a corresponding symmetry. One then figures out that this symmetry corresponds to the helicity operator, $\vec{\Sigma}.\hat{p}\ = \pmatrix{\vec{\sigma} &0 \\ 0 &\vec{\sigma}}.\hat{p}$, such that $[\vec{\Sigma}.\hat{p}\ ,\ H] = 0$. Since, the helicity operator has two eigenvalues they are then associated with the two values spin can take. All good. However, we know that the total angular momentum is also conserved, $[\vec{L}, H] = 0$ where $\vec{L} = \vec{J} + \frac{\hbar}{2} \vec{\Sigma}$. Naturally, there must be a corresponding degeneracy in the solutions to the Dirac equation.
However, I cannot figure out why this degeneracy doesn't come up in the solutions that one calculates using the plane-wave ansatz?
Kindly help me figure this out, thanks!

Have you tried Dirac equation in spherical coordinates?

@Mauricio ohh right, I haven't...I see what you mean - using coordinates naturally adapted to describing angular momentum conservation will manifestly reveal the symmetry associated with it...can you also say if the spherical coordinate solutions also have the spin-degeneracy or do they solely encode the total angular momentum degeneracy?

You get both together. The solutions are Spin spherical harmonics

@Mauricio thanks!
